# c# find replace in word

Tags: c#, replace, ms-word, find

I recently started learning C#.
I'm trying to write some of my macros (written in VBA) in C# - actually I'm trying to make a new ribbon for Word with buttons doing some activities... 
So, I'm trying to make a button doing simple find/replace in active document.
I copied this code from Microsoft site, but it keeps underlining word MISSING:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e){
        Word.Find findObject = Globals.c_sharp.Application.Selection.Find;
        findObject.ClearFormatting();
        findObject.Text = "find me";
        findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
        findObject.Replacement.Text = "Found";

        object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
        findObject.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    }
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: go back to the code you copied and copy the declaration of missing. Its probably some nullvalue from words api. It is underlined - well - because its missing in the code you copied. It would have been faster to look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.execute(v=office.15).aspx then to write this questions - Research comes before asking SO :) the word api is notorious for LOTs of parameters to the methods, that most of the time can be left 'missing' - i.e. not filled with a sensible value

Comment: Actually, I spent quite some time on research before asking. You helped a lot, I added object missing = Type.Missing;

Answer (score 0):

`Type.Missing` is needed in older versions of C#. In current versions, it can be simplified:

```
Globals.c_sharp.Application.ActiveDocument.Content.Find.Execute("find me", 
               Format: false, ReplaceWith: "Found", Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
```